# How do I center the navigation bar and make a container like this?

Tags: html, css

I want to put my navigation bar to the center and the picture left to the navi bar (like the image) And I have troubles making the container (also like the example) how do i code it? [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dhKQ.jpg)

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px; 
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}


li {
  float: left;
  border-right:1px solid #bbb;
  border-color: #87CEFA;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}


li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF51;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" alt:Nintendo Logo>

<ul>
  <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
  <li><a href="E.html">E</a></li> 
</ul>
```

(I'm not making a Nintendo site, I used it just as an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Basically wrap the image and ul in a container div and put display: flex; on it:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-color: #87CEFA;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF51;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" alt:Nintendo Logo>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="E.html">E</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! do you know how i can make the squares (A B C D E) bigger (the width)?

Comment: You can give li a whatever width and height you want. To vertically center the text in the squares after that resize you can give it the same line-height as height

Answer (score 2):

With flexbox you can add a container inside both elements and center align them to the middle.

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #fff;
}


li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    border-color: #87CEFA   ;

}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF51;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/c61469b195ccf8a2f1090f2673258543_-of-the-nintendo-logo-nintendo-logo-clipart_1024-239.gif" />

<ul>
  <li><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
  <li><a href="E.html">E</a></li> 

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! do you know how i can make the squares (A B C D E) bigger (the width)?

Comment: Add a width to your li element or if you want expansion add padding to li a